# sort parent tree list with leaves in front

Tags: python, data-structures

i have a python **parent pointer tree list** in which the index of list indicates the node index and the corrispondent value the parent index in the list:

```
          #1  2   3  4   5  6   7  8  9   10  11  12  13  14
parents = [2, 3, 13, 5, 12, 7, 11, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 0]
```

i also have another list that indicates wheter an element of parents is a leaf:

```
               #1     2      3      4     5      6     7      8     9      10    11     12      13     14
leaves_idx = [True, False, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

now i want remap the **parents list** in such a way that the first 4 element are the leaves and the structure of the tree is maintained:

```
remapped_parents = [6, 5, 7, 9, 12, 8, 11, 13, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 0]


               #1     2      3      4     5      6     7      8     9      10    11     12      13     14
leaves_idx = [True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please be more clear with you language. What is your desired output?

Comment: so you just want to sort `parents` by the indexes and constrain it so that the first four elements are True? how do you treat the other elements do they stay in place or move as well, be more explicit

Comment: @RajanChauhan i post what i want in output.  the other elements must be moved ir order to maintain the tree structure. I want do that because the **treelstm.read_tree** function at this [link](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/treelstm/blob/master/util/read_data.lua)  takes as input parent list ordered in this fashion

Comment: I can see your remapped parents introduces some new nodes. Removing 2 with 6 interesting.

Comment: yes in order to maintain the tree structure

Comment: I can't see any logic there where the node 2 went?

Answer (score 0):

So essentially you want to filter out the leaves in front and the non leaf node at the end.

```
parents = [2, 3, 13, 5, 12, 7, 11, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 0]  
leaves_idx = [True, False, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False]  
leaves = []  
non_leaves = [] 
for i,j in enumerate (leaves_idx):  
    if j==True:  
        leaves.append(parents [i]) #leaves nodes at front  
    else:  
        non_leaves.append(parents [i]) #non leaves at last  
final_list = leaves + non_leaves
```

Here breaking down leaves and non-leaves into two list and concating afterwards.

Comment: @sdrabb Check it out

Comment: i check it the output is  **[2, 5, 7, 9, 3, 13, 12, 11, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 0]**

Comment: Chauahan u not maintain the tree structure

Comment: remapped_parents = [6, 5, 7, 9, 12, 8, 11, 13, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 0]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150659/discussion-between-rajan-chauhan-and-sdrabb).